# Android Firebase: Prevent the sharing of account on more than one device issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to manage users in my firebase app in a way that one account wont be able to be accessed on multiple devices at the same time, but I found a problem in this method:

**The way that I am trying:**

1) UserA signs in with email (`userA@gmail.com`).

2) Database is updated to show that (`userA@gmail.com`) is logged in by device id.

like this:

```
Users
|
|UserA_uid
|--------device_id= "A_CERTAIN_DEVICE_ID"
```

3) UserB attempts to sign in using (`userA@gmail.com`), during that I overwrite the device_id of the userA_uid according to the account.

4) UserA listens to the change **IF HE/SHE WAS CONNECTED TO THE INTERNET**, and according to the device_id change I sign userA out of the app.

5) and so on.

Now All of the above seems to be a clean solution, that allows one account to be opened only once at a time (By kicking off the other user).

**Problem:**

I noticed a problem while testing, and that is:

If users are clever enough,they will do this:

1) UserA signs in with email (`userA@gmail.com`).

2) Database is updated to show that (`userA@gmail.com`) is logged in by device id.

like this:

```
Users
|
|UserA_uid
|--------device_id= "A_CERTAIN_DEVICE_ID"
```

3) **User A shuts the wifi or internet off.**

4) UserB attempts to sign in using (`userA@gmail.com`), during that I overwrite the device_id of the userA_uid according to the account.

5) User A never listens to the change, because he/she is not connected.

6) I end up with user A and user B logged in.

**If you are wondering (my app works offline).**

**Question:**

Can I manage to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of a solution. Check that if it works for you -

1) UserA signs in with email (userA@gmail.com).

2) Database is updated to show that (userA@gmail.com) is logged in by device id. Let the device be A1.

like this:

```
Users
|
|UserA_uid
|--------device_id= "DEVICE_ID (OF DEVICE A1)"
```

3) And when UserA log out from the device (A1), then you should set device_id to be null as -

```
Users
|
|UserA_uid
|--------device_id= "null"
```

4) When UserB attempts to sign in using (userA@gmail.com), then you should fetch the device_id of device (say B1) and you shoud check if device_id (A1) (already existing device_id) is not equal to device_id (B1) (new device) means user has logged in certain device A1. And you should show a message that you are already logged in. And also check if `device_id == null` means UserA has not logged in any device. So he should be able to log in a device say B1, which will update the database as -

```
Users
|
|UserA_uid
|--------device_id= "DEVICE_ID (OF DEVICE B1)"
```

**EDITED**

One solution could be create a broadcast receiver in an app for listening the action "android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" and match the "package name" in `onReceive()` method, if matches start a background thread that monitors the foreground running activities using `ActivityManager`.

When you found foreground activity to be "com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallActivity". It confirms that user wants to uninstall our app. Then start a activity that ask user to logout from the app. Also ensure mobile is connected to internet at this point of time.

Comment: I thought about something similar, but another problem is if user A signs in and uninstalls the app without logging out. Then device_id will always hold the device if of user A and not null. So now no one can ever log in again to this account. Sorry can't upvote because of my reputation. Any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: does this broad cast solution triggers each time I uninstall my app.....why android docs doesn't have this documented?

Comment: Yes it will trigger every time. For more information you can refer docs, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts